# Java can not receive data from AJAX POST

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a newbie of jquery. I am testing a very simple example. Server side (use java) receives data from client side, print it at console. Then response to client side another string.

At client side, I use:

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/",
      data: {
        Name: "sanmao",
        Password: "sanmaoword"
      },

      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "jsonpcallback",
      jsonpCallback: "bc",
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response[0].name + " " + response[1].name);
        //$("#msg").html(decodeURI(data));
      },
      error: function() {

      }
    );
```

At servcer side, I use:

```
InputStream is = exchange.getRequestBody();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String temp = "";
        try {

            // s = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(in);
            temp = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("client request: " + temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Processing failed");
        }

        Headers responseHeaders = exchange.getResponseHeaders();

        responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        OutputStream responseBody = exchange.getResponseBody();
        String s = "bc([{\"lng\":\"" + lng1 + "\",\"lat\":\"" + lat1 + "\",\"name\":\"" + name1 + "\"},{\"lng\":\""
                + lng2 + "\",\"lat\":\"" + lat2 + "\",\"name\":\"" + name2 + "\"}])";
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
        responseBody.write(s.getBytes());
        responseBody.close();
```

But it does not work. If I remove the "data:..." and "contentType...". Client side can receive the response string. But server side can not receive the inbound string.

Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery can't create JSON for you. You have to manually convert the object yourself. You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    Name: "sanmao",
    Password: "sanmaoword"
}),
```

When you pass an object as the data without doing this, jQuery simply converts it to a list of key value pairs which is sent in the post (in format `key1=val1&key2=val2...` instead of JSON).